# Borel summation of a divergent series as the best estimate of a function

Tags: asymptotics, power-series, divergent-series, formal-power-series, summation-method

My current research has me working with series of the form $\sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n z^n$, $z\in\mathbb{C}$ that usually have zero convergence radius (they diverge for all values of $z$). Due to unrelated reasons, I need to assume that each of these series is asymptotic to some function $f(z)$ that is well-defined near $z=0$ (not necesarily  at $z=0$): $f(z)\sim \sum_{n=0}^\infty  f_n z^n$.

As it is stated [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_summation) (under the uniqueness section), a series can be asymptotic to many functions, and the best possible estimate is the finite function $\sum_{n=0}^N f_n z^n$, for $N>0$ such that the truncation error $\mathcal{E}(z,N)\equiv f(z)-\sum_{n=0}^N f_n z^n$ is minimum. Obviusly, if one does not know $f(z)$, $\mathcal{E}(z,N)$ cannot be computed and minimized.

It is a customary practice in my field (and it is also mentioned in the link above) to believe that the procedure of Borel summation (for which $f(z)$ does not need to be known) returns the best possible estimate of $f(z)$ that can be constructed with the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n z^n$. However I have found no formal proof of this, and several questions arise:

1. Does the Borel sum return the same estimate one would obtain if $f(z)$ was known and $\mathcal{E}(z,N)$ could be minimized? Or is it "the best possible estimate *given $f(z)$ is not known*"?
2. In any of the two above cases, is there any proof?
3. The link indicates Watson's theorem and Carelman's theorem do show Borel summation produces the best estimate, but I fail to see how.

I am only interested in series whose coefficients $f_n$ grow as $a^n n^b n!$ for $a,b$ constants, so a proof that Borel summation is returns the best estimate for that class of divergent series is enough.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This does not answer your questions but may be helpful. The optimal truncation index $N=N(z)$ will depend on the singularity structure of the Borel transform. You can write down the Borel transform about the origin as a convergent power series and apply Padé approximations to it. The poles of the Padé approximants will accumulate around the singularities visible from the origin. If the nearest singularity is $t_0$, $N(z)\approx |t_0 z|$. You may look up exponential asymptotics, hyperasymptotics, Écalle theory, etc.

Comment: @Gary Thanks for the comment. The relation between $N(z)$ and the poles of the Borel transfor was not known to me, and it is in fact really interesting. I'll make sure to check the topics you mentioned.

Comment: Note that in general the Borel transform may have singularities other than poles, e.g., algebraic branch points or transcendental singularities.